# Quick move plank to primary monitor

Tags: display, plank, release-juno

Use Juno release. I have a laptop and often connect an external monitor to it. When an external monitor is connected, I make it primary.

I added hotkeys/commands:

Win+PageUp: xrandr --output eDP-1 --primary
Win+PageDown: xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary

It works well. But Dock (Plank) move with delay. Can I fix this? Add command for Plank?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/abiosoft/autoplank/blob/master/README.md

Haven't tried it but seems to help automate it without having to run those commands